# How to call __setitem__ without calling __getitem__ on dict wrapper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I made a dict wrapper named `CustomDict` which consists of keys and `CustomValues`. CustomValue has `__iadd__` (`+=`) operation defined. This operation adds an object to the list named `self.lines`.

```
class CustomValue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []
    def __iadd__(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

class CustomDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.data:
            self.data[key] = CustomValue()
        return self.data[key]

    # this doesn't feel pythonic
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        pass

def main():
    d = CustomDict()
    d['key0'] += 'Line 1'
    d['key0'] += 'Line 2'
    d['key1'] += 'Line 3'
    d['key1'] += 'Line 4'
    print(d)
```

This is what I see in debugger that happens after call `d['key0'] += 'Line 1'`:

```
d.__getitem__('key0').__iadd__('Line 1')
d.__setitem__('key0', None)
```

As you can see, I had to define `__setitem__` just with `pass` because when it is called like this, parameter `value` is `None`. So now it works but I have a redundant call to `__setitem__`. And if I remove and comment it out, I get this error:

`TypeError: 'CustomDict' object does not support item assignment`.

What is the correct way of doing this?

**Default dict Edit**

Based on [user2357112 supports Monica answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819578/10732434) I wrote this:

```
import collections

class Key:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []
    def __iadd__(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

def missing():
    return Key()

d = collections.defaultdict(missing)
d['key0'] += 'Line 1'
print(d['key0'])
```

But the problem is new key is not inserted back to defaultdict and print statement prints `None`. What am I doing wrong?

**Dict subclass Edit**

I checked what ends up in CustomDict using [Jordan Brière's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59819572/10732434) and there are some redundant keys. I wrote a `__repr__` test:

```
class CustomValue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []
    def __iadd__(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)
        return self
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'CustomValue {}, {}'.format(self.__hash__(), self.lines)

class CustomDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        key = self[key] = CustomValue()
        return key
    def __repr__(self):
        return '\n'.join(['{}: {}'.format(key, self[key]) for key in self])

def main():
    d = CustomDict()
    d['key0'] += 'Line 1'
    d['key0'] += 'Line 2'
    d['key1'] += 'Line 3'
    d['key1'] += 'Line 4'
    print(d)
```

Which prints:

```
CustomValue 1090233, ['Line 1', 'Line 2']: CustomValue 1090233, ['Line 1', 'Line 2']
key0: CustomValue 1090233, ['Line 1', 'Line 2']
CustomValue 1090235, ['Line 3', 'Line 4']: CustomValue 1090235, ['Line 3', 'Line 4']
key1: CustomValue 1090235, ['Line 3', 'Line 4']
```

As you can see some CustomValues are keys which is not what I want.

Comment: Concerning your edit; look at my answer. Your issue is that you do not `return self` in your `__iadd__` method. Also, no need to wrap the factory into a function; `defaultdict(Key)` is the same minus a redundant layer.

Comment: Concerning your second edit; this is normal because of the `__missing__` method which generates a new `CustomValue` bound to the requested keys that cannot be found. This is exactly the behaviour of your original code: `if key not in self.data: self.data[key] = CustomValue()`.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Just to show you that my code doesn't have this error I made a similar `__repr__` test [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJgjdlmZU).

Comment: That is because you do nothing into `__setitem__`, and thus items are never assigned. I've edited my answer to add an override of that method which will ignore keys that are `CustomValue` objects which should give you the result you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to provide (or use) a meaningful item assignment operator, then you shouldn't use `+=`. `+=` is an assignment. Assignments gonna assign. Your `CustomValue` can provide an `append` method or something instead of `+=`.

I see 3 reasonable options here. Number 1 is to change `CustomValue` to use something other than `+=`. Number 2 is to change `CustomDict` to provide a meaningful `__setitem__`.

Number 3 is to ditch these `CustomDict` and `CustomValue` classes and just use a stdlib `collections.defaultdict(list)`:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
d['key0'].append('Line 1')  # or d['key0'] += ['Line 1'] if you really like operators
d['key0'].append('Line 2')
d['key1'].append('Line 3')
d['key1'].append('Line 4')
print(d)
```

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a `dict` subclass that uses a provided factory function to generate default values for missing keys. It's more efficient and much more feature-rich than your `CustomDict`.

Comment: It looks really nice, I just have a small problem with `default_factory` method. I edited my answer.

Comment: @sanitizedUser: As Jordan Brière commented, `__iadd__` needs to return `self`. `+=` will assign `__iadd__`'s return value back into where the original value was retrieved from.

Answer (score 2):

You should really just subclass `dict` and override the operations needed to achieve your implementation. Having an internal `data` dictionary is redundant. E.g.

```
class CustomValue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []
    def __iadd__(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)
        return self

class CustomDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        key = self[key] = CustomValue()
        return key

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        if isinstance(item, CustomValue):
            return
        super().__setitem__(item, value)

def main():
    d = CustomDict()
    d['key0'] += 'Line 1'
    d['key0'] += 'Line 2'
    d['key1'] += 'Line 3'
    d['key1'] += 'Line 4'
    print(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your main question:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq1HT.png)

just don't use += ,and use + operator , no need to assign anything
and it will work just fine,

Answer to your 2nd question using defaultdict:

just return self from your dunder add method:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQzE4.png)

and after adding it will return the Key() object itself with updated lines attribute, and it will be assigned to the the kay in your dictionary for which you are adding the line in first place

Sorry but i did not even read subclass answer, as i dont think we need to do so much things in order to achieve such simpler thing, as we already have defaultdict, and it perfectly solves what you are trying to achieve here, let me know if you still want a simpler soln to subclass answer, i will try to read it and solve it

Comment: Hi Jatin Goyal, welcome to SO. Please do not add code as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Instead, add the code in a codeblock e.g three backticks "````" without the quotes, then add code on a new line, then three backticks on a new line after the code. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer is a duplicate of what has already been mentioned in other answers and comments.